# Multiple gateway + load balancing in linux gateway

Tags: linux, load-balancing, failover, ip-routing

i have a problem with load balancing/Fail-overing with Linux gateway

my network look-like this

[image]

now, i want users in internal LAN (192.168.1.x), has connect with both line.

is any solution

excuse me for my English, thankyou

Comment: What exactly is it you want to achieve? Fail-over? Load balancing? Increased uplink speed? And where doe these other two networks go? What's in the cloud on the right?

Comment: fail over and increase speed, yes, in left its Internet cloud.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple fail-over configuration you'll need two default routes with different metrics on the linux box. The one with the lower metric is the normal default gateway, the other one kicks in if the normal default gateway is down.

Speed increase cannot be achieved this way. For this you would need to trunk the connections, but since they reach into different networks, that is not possible.

Plus: The cloud on the right cannot be the public Internet. Addresses in the 192.168.x.y range cannot be routed on the public Internet. So what is it?

Comment: for the cloud, you right, but there is address in adsl modem range. i don't sketch them.

Comment: thank you for your question, for fail-over can give you me a link?

Comment: Just follow my instructions, it will work.